# How can I get the date and or time to accompany anything printed to the console in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

Every time something gets printed to the console in PyCharm, I want the date and or time to go with it, so I can easily organize events. Basically:
`[02/12 13:00] Hello World!`
`[02/12 13:05] 1 + 2 = 3`
etc
As of right now, I manually add in the date.time (or whatever it's called) function every time I print, so I can see when something gets printed. This is fine, but I'd rather not have to do the whole ensemble every time I need to check a time-sensitive print.

Now, I just manually add in the date and time. It works, just really tedious and bloating.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

print(f"{datetime.datetime.now()}: This is a message with the current date and time.")
```

You can customize the format of the date and time by using the strftime method, which takes a format string as an argument. The format string %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S represents the year, month, day, hour, minute, and second, respectively. The code would look like this.

```
import datetime

print(f"{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}: This is a message with the current date and time.")
```

The output would be:
2023-02-13 13:41:30: This is a message with the current date and time.